# $\operatorname E(Y_i^2\mid X_i=x) $in regression

Tags: regression, expected-value, variance

I have a regression equation of the form
\begin{equation}
Y_i = f(X_i) + \varepsilon_i
\end{equation}

I'm trying to figure out what $\operatorname E(Y_i^2\mid X_i=x)$ in this case. I know that 
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Var}(Y_i\mid X_i=x) = \operatorname E(Y_i^2\mid X_i=x)-(\operatorname E(Y_i\mid X_i=x))^2.
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
\operatorname E(Y_i\mid X_i=x) = f(x)
\end{equation}
but I'm unsure how to figure out what $\operatorname E(Y_i^2\mid X_i=x)$ is.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[Y_i^2|X_i=x] &= Var(Y_i|X_i = x) + ( \mathbb{E}[Y_i|X_i = x] )^2 \\
&=Var(f(X) + \epsilon_i|X_i = x) + ( \mathbb{E}[f(X) + \epsilon_i|X_i=x] ) ^ 2 \\
& = Var(\epsilon_i|X) + ( f(x_i) + \mathbb{E}[\epsilon_i|X] ) ^ 2\\
& = \sigma^2 + f^2(x_i). 
\end{align}